# Showing "frequently bought together" products?

Tags: magento2, related-products

Does Magento keep any data on products that were purchased along with a specific product? I know that there is a "Product View" report, but I'm wondering if there is similar data available for "bought together".

I do know that there are "bought together" extensions available out there but I'm wanting to know if this is based on historical data or data that is collected once the extension is installed.

Answer (score 0):

The only mean I know, as you mentioned, is by extensions. Which usually are: who bought this also bought.

I have tried to get data from Google Analytics, but couldn't end up in a reasonable conclusion. You have where customers interacted with your website, but it is hard to postulate a theory about a same customer behavior. Sorry for not helping with a different view ate this time.

Answer (score 0):

> I do know that there are "bought together" extensions available out
> there but I'm wanting to know if this is based on historical data or
> data that is collected once the extension is installed.

As the author of one of these modules, I can tell you about the principle by which mine works.

---

*Also Bought* products are formed based on orders. For each of these three products, the other two corresponding products will be displayed as *Also Bought* products.

The list of *Also Bought* products is generated **automatically** according to a cron schedule or **manually** when executing a CLI command or from Admin.